# Auto width for jQuery UI datepicker not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use the datepicker gadget for different languages, where some languages might have more characters for week names and some (like english) will have only 3 characters for short week names ie dayNamesMin.

[image]

As you seee above, except IE7, width adjusts automatically with

```
.ui-datepicker {width: auto;}
```

in most of the other browsers.

Has anybody faced this problem ? Any good suggestion to fix ie7 width problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seemed to do the trick (but I am not sure):

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 2.6em;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 0.2em;
    right: 0.2em;
}
.ui-datepicker table {
    width: auto;
}
```

I have:

- Made the outermost div auto width (to override hard-coded width)

  - And added top padding (see below)
- Made the header absolute positioned since

  - Neither 100% nor auto width worked in IE7 (under given conditions) so used `left: 0` + `right: 0`
  - The top padding occupies the room needed for the header
- The table is set to auto width as 100% does not seem to work in IE7 (under given conditions)

[**Code here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/tTnK2/) / [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/tTnK2/show/)